# Dimensionality of the Poincare section?

Tags: dynamical-systems, dimensional-analysis

Consider the Poincare map $P$, for which we place the Poincare section transverse to the trajectories and it intersects at various points which forms a set of discrete points.

[image]

For $\dot{x} = f(x)$ where $x$ is an $n$ dimensional vector, why the section $S$ is an $n-1$ dimensional surface? How can I visualize this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two angles for explanation:

- The Poincaré map is supposed to remove exactly one dimension from the dynamics: The one corresponding to time. All other dimensions must still be present in the Poincaré map. Hence it’s state space must have dimension $n-1$. As the state space consists of points of the Poincaré section, the section also must have dimension $n-1$.
- For most applications, you want the Poincaré map to have one iteration per oscillation¹. Hence, the Poincaré section has to be frequently intersected. Now, very loosely speaking, a trajectory segment (a one-dimensional object) has a probability of zero to hit any object (the Poincaré section) with dimension $n-2$ or lower, while it cannot miss an $n-1$-dimensional object. Of course, for some dynamics you may carefully place an $n-2$-dimensional section such that it is hit for sure, but this would mean that your dynamics has a spurious dimension.

---

<sup>¹ otherwise it’s every other oscillation, every high-amplitude oscillation, or similar, but the argument stays essentially the same</sup>

Comment: How the Poincare map removes exactly one dimension(the time) from the dynamics? is it because the map is time independent? like $x_{n+1} = f(x_{n})$? where as its continous version still has time like $\frac{dx}{dt}=f(x)$ ?

Comment: @BAYMAX: I am not sure I get your question here, but the question in your comment seems to be asked the wrong way around. The Poincaré map removes one dimension because $S$ is $n-1$-dimensional. $S$ is chosen this way because otherwise we wouldn’t get a useful map. (Also see my edit.)